# How to select a database in Postgres with PHP?

Tags: php, sql, postgresql

I have the following string connection:

```
$string_connection = "host=localhost port=5432 user=postgres password=postgres";
$conn = pg_connect($string_connection );
```

Later in my code, I need to select a database:

```
pg_connect("dbname=my_database");
```

But, always I have the following error:

```
Warning: pg_connect(): Unable to connect to PostgreSQL server: fe_sendauth: no password supplied in ..\class.databases.php on line 142
```

But, in the example of PHP.net, they do this.
Another example:

```
pg_query($conn,'\connect my_database');
```

Why this dont work?

When I do a backup with PgAdmin, I got the following strings:

```
SET statement_timeout = 0;
SET client_encoding = 'UTF8';
SET standard_conforming_strings = off;
SET check_function_bodies = false;
SET client_min_messages = warning;
SET escape_string_warning = off;

DROP DATABASE my_database;

CREATE DATABASE my_database WITH ENCODING = 'UTF8' LC_COLLATE = 'Portuguese_Brazil.1252' LC_CTYPE = 'Portuguese_Brazil.1252';

ALTER DATABASE my_database OWNER TO postgres;

\connect my_database
```

Whe I try to run this script with pg_query, I have erros:

```
Warning: pg_query(): Query failed: ERRO: syntax error in "\" LINE 1: \connect my_database ^
```

I need to select a dabatase to create a schema then create my tables... I dont know how to do this with Postgres.

Comment: Why not select the database when you initially run `pg_connect`?

Comment: Because the user will select or create a database, where it can create a schema and then run a set of queries / sql script.

Comment: In that case, you're going to have to pass all the parameters in on the second pg_connect call, I think. I assume the examples on php.net are for databases that don't require passwords for a connection.

Comment: Yeah, I think too. But what about the pg_query($conn,'\connect my_database'); ?

Comment: Where did you see that code? I can't find it on the php.net pages for pg_connect or pg_query.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pgsql.php#73837 A down-voted comment of 6 years old. And I see in the generated sql of the PgAdmin backup the string \connect, and I thinked maybe was possible do this with pg_query.

Comment: Ah, I see. I think it's the same issue - the database is presumably configured not to need a password in that case; it's hard to be sure, though. I think it's theoretically possible to do what you want, but you'll need to make sure that you can connect to the database with only a database name.

Comment: Yeah, I think ill close and reconnect with database name. Thanks for the answer @andrewsi.

Comment: You could also think about wrapping this in a class or a function that would take care of the connection for you - so you just need to call a function along with a database name, and that will make the connection for you. You can store the connection details in that function, so they are only in one place.

Comment: Yes, Im doing this. I have a method in my class called selectDatabase, and another method Connect... Now Im storing the others param in properties and calling the method Connect with the name of database as param.

Answer (score 2):

Add "dbname=my_database" to your connection string to select a database at conection time.

Comment: Yeah, I know, but if need to change the database after? I need to close and re-connect?